# Can I create a single content type to use on a list and a document library?

Tags: list, document-library, content-type

I want to create a single content type to define columns for both a SharePoint list and a Document Library in SharePoint 2013.

I have tried creating a Content type with Items as the Parent and added it to my "Custom Content Types" group, but when I try to add it on the document library I can't find the content type to add it. But I can find it for my List. 
Some content types like Video are available in both the List and Document Library.

I think I just need the correct parent on my content type.

Can anyone give me some more information about how I need to set this up?

edit:
Just some additional information.
The reason I want both to have the same information is because I am setting up somewhere for publishing to store the list of documents they can printing. For a majority of the documents they have a file. But for some documents copyright restrictions mean they can't keep a digital copy. So I wanted to be able to store the documents in a document library but then I will also need a list for the items that we can't keep copies of, but then I need to be able to display both together for the users that want to search for what is available for printing from the publishing department. A content query web part wants items that have the same content type to be able to display the data together.

Comment: How about a list with attachments?

Answer (score 5):

Document library require content types that are inherited from Document Content Type. This is required because it needs a File field to store the file data.

In case of Custom List, it is just like an Excel File with columns (Meta data) and don't require a mandatory File object (in case of doc lib)

Also I don't think its a good design to have both using the same content type.

Comment: I tried using the document content type as a parent, but this still doesn't let me use the custom content type on the item list.

Comment: It will not work.. That is what I was explaining in my post.